# How do i ignore a specific field from an list in JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to ignore a specified field from a list during deserialization. I am not sure how do i do that for a field that sits inside a list. Below is my json and response class

**Sample json**

```
{
  "key": {
    "rowKey": "123"
  },
  "names": [
    {
      "firstName": "JON ",
      "firstNameFormatted": "JON"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Response class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Data {


    private Map<String,Object> key;


    private List<Map<String,Object>> names;
    
   

}
```

Here i would like to ignore

> firstNameFormatted

from my json response but i am not sure how to do that using jackson for a field that is inside a list ?

Comment: That field is inside an object, by the way, not a list.

Comment: But, in general, you cannot use `Map<String,Object>`, you'd need an object and field annotated with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: sorry i didn't understand when u say object and field annotated ? are you refering to a map in this case ?

Comment: I mean create a class in place of a map that you can serialize an object that'll ignore some `String firstNameFormatted` field

Comment: okay understood

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has a solution for that. Simply use `@JsonIgnore`
You can see it in the example below

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

Now the password information won’t be serialized to JSON.

Also you can try with `@JsonIgnoreProperties`